# See if a pointer in an array is empty (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers

I have an array of pointers to a class called cPlayer.

Compiler: Visual C++ 2010 Express

**Init**

```
cPlayer* players[MAX_PLAYERS];
```

Max_Players is a defined value of 10.
defined in a class called "OnlineData", in a header.

**Checking**

```
if (players[a]){
   // some code here
}
```

What ever I have tried, it still gets through to //some code here

**Players are deleted like this:**

```
players[player->id]=0;
delete player;
```

**Question**

I want to check if item at position a in the players array has a value. I am using it to resort the player list (defragmentation)

The array works normalling in adding content, until i try to do the above thing

Comment: did u try (players[a] == null)

Comment: @BhanuKaushik That wouldn't be valid C++

Comment: it's not exactly clear what your question is. Did you intend to post your question like it is now?

Comment: I did, it said == can not be used in this instance, or something close to that, and also null is not defined

Comment: @Benj- My bad. seems like i was in the wrong thread.

Comment: @Rubenwardy your `delete` looks peculiar but you haven't posted enough of it to be sure.  If you're setting a pointer to `0` before calling `delete` you'll be introducing a leak.

Comment: You should include the definition of NULL (note the capitols in NULL) in your program. Setting elements of playes to NULL is perfectly legal.

Comment: @Benj, it is not a leak, player is a cPlayer* and players is an array of cPlayer*'s. I delete the player from the array, then i delete the player

Comment: @bert-jan Setting a pointer to `0` in a C++ program is entirely sufficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To initialize a global or local array you would use:

```
cPlayer* players[MAX_PLAYERS] = {};
```

However since your array is a class member you can't do this (until C++11 introduced in-class initialization, but VS2010 does not support this feature). Instead you have to write code that initializes each member individually in your constructor bodies (or init function or whatever):

```
struct S {
    cPlayer *players[MAX_PLAYERS];

    S() {
        for (int i=0; i<MAX_PLAYERS; ++i) {
            players[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
};
```

Or better than using an explicit loop would be to use something from `<algorithm>`, such as `std::fill` or `std::fill_n`:

```
std::fill_n(players, MAX_PLAYERS, NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you all for your very quick help

Comment: or `std::fill_n(players, 10, 0)`

Answer (score 10):

Initialize your pointers to null pointers, which can be done like this:

```
cPlayer* players[MAX_PLAYERS] = {};
```

Comment: @Rubenwardy: Please provide a complete example of the code you are trying to compile.  Because I can assure you with utmost confidence that there are no errors in this line of code, unless `cPlayer` and `MAX_PLAYERS` are not defined. [example](http://ideone.com/PBhic)

Comment: The issue is that players is a class member. See my answer @Rubenwardy

Comment: @Anirudha You are incorrect; for a normal array `T t[N] = {};` would initialize the entire array. See § 8.5.1/7

Comment: @Anirudha: You are wrong, I'm afraid.  Whenever you provide an initializer to an array, all elements unspecified are value initialized.  For pointers, value initialization means initialization to NULL.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize the array:-  cPlayer* players[MAX_PLAYERS] = {};

Comment: Initialize it with {0} and check?

Comment: `{}` and `{0}` will do the same thing in this case. I think using `{0}` is a bad idea because I keep hearing from people that have somehow gotten the idea that `{x}` will initialize every element with `x` and I think they get that idea from `{0}`. The fact is that when you initialize an aggregate with a list of fewer items than the aggregate contains, all the remaining elements basically get value-initialized. So `{0}` initializes the first element with `0` and all the rest with value-initialization; that happens to be the same as `0` in this case, but doesn't have to be.

Comment: @bames53:- Thanks a lot for sharing this point. I really got a better picture of it now :)

Answer (score 1):

Initialize all the values of the array to NULL (found at `<cstdlib>`). Then, when you want to assign a value to one of the positions of the array, write: `players[i]=new cPlayer(...)`. To check if a position `a` is empty, simply check if `players[a]==NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`std::fill_n(players, 10, 0)`

to initalize all members to 0..

Comment: @Rubenwardy hope that helps now